CoxPHFitter and WeibullAFTFitter() lifelines implementation
I am trying to build a survival model to predict years of life lost; currently, I am running several different survival analysis methods to compare their results: AFT and Cox PH.
I am using the lifelines package and I wanted to ask to anyone experienced if I should scale the data (z score) before using it in the model.
Also, my data is not balanced as I have way more dead people than alive. Should I account for this somehow in the models?
Thanks a lot!

I'm not sure about the implementation in lifelines, but the R coxph() function internally centers and scales continuous predictors to minimize numerical overflow problems arising from the exponentiations that are involved in the fitting. The coefficient estimates are then re-expressed in the original scale before returning the results, however.
Thus it might be safest to scale your data if you don't know whether lifelines routines do that internally. Results will be easiest to explain to others if you then re-express the coefficients in the original scale.
Dead/alive imbalance of the type you describe isn't at all a problem with survival models. Individuals with known event times (those who died, in your situation) provide more information for the models than do those with censored event times (those last known to be alive). If you had the reverse problem (many more alive than dead), the models would still handle the data but coefficient estimates would be less precise and there would be a larger risk of informative censoring leading to unreliable results.
